# ReactiveUI Dialog Fragment with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android-fragments, mvvm, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I am using reactiveUI 7.4 with VS 2017. I want a  Dialog Fragment where I can use `Bind` Method like ReactiveFragment. Are there any implementation on this. I was able to find following for java. But not for c#. Could someone guide me.
Thanks!
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/8c196c59affe79d4015552751c820fe513de0bb7/rxandroid-framework/src/main/java/rx/android/observables/ReactiveDialog.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found one either, we created one, it's available on github if that can help you to create your own : 
https://github.com/Ideine/Xmf2/blob/cdbe0abd2f924f5668ac2791fbc7fba3b22ddf71/src/Xmf2.Rx.Droid/BaseView/XMFReactiveDialogFragment.cs